# How to Simulate Jar files on PC

Tags: jar, j2me

Sometimes it happens that after downloading a Jar file for an App, there appears to be several catch with it, like activation code required. Is there any tool that I can use to simulate the Jar file on desktop prior to downloading/transferring to mobile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a J2ME emulator, there are many of them and it appears that many have some limitations such as limited 3D support, slowness and other bugs.

There is [Micro Emulator](http://microemu.org/) which according to [this site](http://techie-buzz.com/how-to/run-opera-mini-5-on-desktop.html) can run Opera Mini and is an indication that it is reasonably complete.

I also found [Java Emulator](http://www.javaemulator.com/java-emulator.php) which looks to be more game orientated.

[MPowerPlayer](http://mpowerplayer.com/) also appears to have another Java MIDP emulator as reviewed [here](http://thinkabdul.com/2007/11/25/mpowerplayer-free-midp-20-emulator-to-preview-test-java-j2me-jarjad-mobile-games-applications-software-on-computer/)

There are just [too many emulators to count](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=j2me+emulator+for+pc), and you're going to have to review them to see which suits your needs best.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up :). I now have resources to look into and evaluate.

Comment: On first hand experience, Java Emulator looks to be better. I tried with one app from Mobilerated, Micro Emulator crashed but Java Emulator was successful.